# Android: dynamic loading shared libraries

Tags: android, c, linux, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I have 2 shared libraries: **lib1.so** and **lib2.so**.

**lib1.so** contains some functions which are defined in **lib2.so**. From a C program I load **lib1.so** using following call:

```
dlopen( "lib1.so", RTLD_NOW );
```

Both libraries are presented in the current directory. My program works under a desktop Linux (Ubuntu, Debian), but not under Android. Under Android dlopen returns an Error and exits. I tried to set:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:.
```

but it doesn't help.

I am totally confused, why this code doesn't work under Android. I cannot find any good documentation on Android's dynamic linker. So, I have no explanation why it doesn't work.

DETAILS:

1. Android with Linux kernel 2.6.35 armv7l
2. objdump shows lib1.so needs libc.so and lib2.so
3. objdump shows lib2.so needs only libc.so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I just found a solution. Adding -lgcc to linker options for lib1.so has solved it. It looks like compiler has auto-generated some calls to special built-in functions from libgcc. It also requires -lc because compiler also auto-generates special calls to memcpy.

Answer (score 1):

if `dlopen` does not work for some reason, have you tried to call `dlerror` to find out what the real problem is?

Comment: dlerror(): Cannot load library: reloc_library[1311]: 23061 cannot locate '__aeabi_fcmpgt'...

Answer (score 0):

I not very sure about your project.
But I think, it better to load you library from a Service using System.loadLibrary).

System.loadLibrary(lib.so);
In your case first load lib2.so and then only load lib1.so